# Loop over first n elements of Lua table

Tags: loops, lua

I have a for loop in which I'm doing some action that I want to do only max n times. So far I have done this by means of a local variable which I increment in the loop, and each time check to see if it exceeded the counter limit. If it does, I break out of the loop.

```
for _,u in GetAllUnits() do
        if not u:IsInCategory("STRUCTURE") and not u:IsInCategory("COMMAND") then
                NameUnit(u)
                nameCount = nameCount + 1
                if nameCount >= maxUnitNames then break end
        end
end
```

I'm very new to Lua and wonder if there is a better way to do this. It's important that I don't end up creating a copy of the table or some other expensive operation.

Note that the `_` contains the ID of the unit, so this cannot be used instead of the counter.

Comment: What is your concern with your current method?

Comment: You could also alter  GetAllUnits() to accept as parameter the maximum number of items to return.  So, you effectively move the 'if .. break' code inside  GetAllUnits()

Comment: @tonypdmtr Uh, doesn't "All" mean something different?

Comment: I think there is no better way.

Comment: @TomBlodget 1. I didn't choose the name, 2. It's a matter of interpretation, e.g., "All I care about" :)

Comment: @tonypdmtr You raise a good point: "All" can have a context. In the original function, it's hidden; So I should have directed my comment at the asker.

Comment: I cannot easily change  `GetAllUnits` as it is defined in code I don't control.

Comment: My problem with the current approach is that it is VERY imperative. The low level details clutter the code, making it less clean. I understand that I'm in the minority when it comes to caring about that, yet I do :)

Comment: @tonypdmtr Even if the OP could modify `GetAllUnits`, limiting the number of units it returns could change the result of the loop because the category condition wouldn't be taken into account (`nameCount` only counts units that are not in the "STRUCTURE" or "COMMAND" categories).

Comment: @tony19 And, right you are!  (I didn't look at it enough to notice the counting was inside the condition and not just the FOR loop.)  So, not that simple then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are concerned about the imperative nature of that piece of code, you can always use the usual functional approaches:

```
local function notStructureNotCommand( _, u )
  return not u:IsInCategory( "STRUCTURE" ) and
         not u:IsInCategory( "COMMAND" )
end

for _,u in take( maxUnitNames, filter( notStructureNotCommand, GetAllUnits() ) ) do
  NameUnit( u )
end
```

You can do functional programming quite nicely in Lua, but you'll have to look for the usual helper functions like `map`, `filter`, etc. in an external library. There are a lot of implementations of those functions in the [LuaRocks](https://luarocks.org/) repository, but in your case you have to make sure that you get a version that works on iterators instead of (or in addtion to) tables. If you don't find anything suitable, you can use the functions below:

```
local filter
do
  local function filter_helper( pred, f, s, var_1, ... )
    if var_1 ~= nil then
      if pred( var_1, ... ) then
        return var_1, ...
      else
        return filter_helper( pred, f, s, f( s, var_1 ) )
      end
    end
  end

  function filter( pred, f, s, var )
    return function( st, v )
      return filter_helper( pred, f, st, f( st, v ) )
    end, s, var
  end
end


local function take( n, f, s, var )
  return function( st, v )
    if n > 0 then
      n = n - 1
      return f( st, v )
    end
  end, s, var
end
```